# Linq and Ternary opeartor

Tags: c#-4.0

Following code works but in ternary operator I have to get value of "Content" field 2 times, Is there any way to store the value of "Content" field in a variable and then make caparison?

```
List<MPContentSearchResultItem> list = (from result in results
                                     select new MPContentSearchResultItem()
                                     {  
                                         Content = string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Content"), 300)) ? GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Circumstances"), 300) :GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Content"), 300)
                                     }).ToList();
```

Condition is if "Content" field is empty or have null value then get value from "Circumstances" filed otherwise get value from "Content" field.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the result of a sub-expression by using the [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
from result in results
let contentSummary = GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Content"), 300)
select new MPContentSearchResultItem()
{  
    Content = string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentSummary) ? GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Circumstances"), 300) : contentSummary
};
```

The variable `contentSummary` will be only available inside the query.

You could do the same with the somehow lengthy sub-expression `result.Document.GetItem()` (might not always mean less typing but can make things easier to read):

```
from result in results
let item = result.Document.GetItem()
let contentSummary = GetSummary(item.GetFieldValue("Content"), 300)
select new MPContentSearchResultItem()
{  
    Content = string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentSummary) ? GetSummary(item.GetFieldValue("Circumstances"), 300) : contentSummary
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
var query = from result in results
            let content = GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Content"), 300)
            select new MPContentSearchResultItem()
            {  
                Content = string.IsNullOrEmpty(content)
                    ? GetSummary(result.Document.GetItem().GetFieldValue("Circumstances"), 300)
                    : content
            };

List<MPContentSearchResultItem> list = query.ToList();
```